# SagePay express checkout?

Tags: opayo

In case your wondering Sage Pay documentation page led me here.

https://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/support-forum

So my question here is that is there an express checkout integration for Sage Pay?

The best example is PayPal's Express Checkout which is basically just a script you need to paste in your page to work.

I found this: https://github.com/SagePayments/PaymentsJS

But upon further reading, I discovered this is not Sage Pay and that it's just using Sage Pay for their services so using it is impossible if we're registered with Sage Pay.

I'm looking into their Integration guide but I find it a bit hard to understand. I was hoping they have a GitHub page somewhere that is more understandable than what they have on their site.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible - Google 'Sage Pay Direct Protocol' and start at around page 21. (I did previously post a link, but that was deleted)